# Calling a private method inside every JUnit before any test steps

Tags: java, junit

I want to know if there is any technical difference between the following, when writing JUnit tests:

**Option 1:**
Define a setup method, i.e annotated with `@Before`, to initialize test fixture state before any `@Test` method is run.

**Option 2:**
Define a private method - just a plain old private method without any annotation - that does the same initialization, and make the first line of every `@Test` method a call to this method. (Ignore the possibility of someone forgetting to call the method in every test. I am looking for technical differences, not human factors)

*Example of Option 2:*

```
public class MyTest {

    private void runSetupLogic() {
        // whatever @Before method would have done
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        runSetupLogic();
        // test logic
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod2() {
        runSetupLogic();
        // test logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you read [*the doc*](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html) ?

Comment: The main point of difference is that @Before is automatic and doesn't rely on test method authors. Hard to see why you wouldn't take advantage of that.

Comment: Thanks, alfasin. I guess this is what you were pointing me to: "The @Before methods of superclasses will be run before those of the current class."

Comment: @EJP: That advantage is, of course, there but I wanted to know if there is any technical difference. I asked because I had just read a question about the difference between using `@BeforeClass` or doing the one-time initialization in the test class constructor. There IS a difference and the answer explained that. So I thought checking what is special about `@Before`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not really **exactly** the same, but for all intents and purposes either way should be fine. However, if you are interested in the technical analysis then my shaky understanding of the current JUnit 4 code on Github follows:

Here is what seems to be the actual code being ran when you use `@Before` using the default JUnit 4 runner [src/main/java/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java):

```
/**
 * Returns a {@link Statement}: run all non-overridden {@code @Before}
 * methods on this class and superclasses before running {@code next}; if
 * any throws an Exception, stop execution and pass the exception on.
 */
protected Statement withBefores(FrameworkMethod method, Object target,
        Statement statement) {
    List<FrameworkMethod> befores = getTestClass().getAnnotatedMethods(
            Before.class);
    return befores.isEmpty() ? statement : new RunBefores(statement,
            befores, target);
}
```

The above calls RunBefores in [src/main/java/org/junit/internal/runners/statements/RunBefores.java](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/internal/runners/statements/RunBefores.java):

```
public class RunBefores extends Statement {
    private final Statement next;

    private final Object target;

    private final List<FrameworkMethod> befores;

    public RunBefores(Statement next, List<FrameworkMethod> befores, Object target) {
        this.next = next;
        this.befores = befores;
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
        for (FrameworkMethod before : befores) {
            before.invokeExplosively(target);
        }
        next.evaluate();
    }
```

The invokeExplosively method definition is in [src/main/java/org/junit/runners/model/FrameworkMethod.java](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/model/FrameworkMethod.java):

```
public Object invokeExplosively(final Object target, final Object... params)
        throws Throwable {
    return new ReflectiveCallable() {
        @Override
        protected Object runReflectiveCall() throws Throwable {
            return method.invoke(target, params);
        }
    }.run();
}
```

which seems to use reflection to invoke the methods annotated with `@Before`.

Anyway, hope this answer is somewhat correct, but I'm not sure. If anyone has any corrections I can edit them in from the comments. By the way, for reference here is the javadoc for the `@Before` annotation: http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Before.html

Comment: Thanks, Christian & Stefan. I knew that the `@Before` methods of all superclasses will be called (just like constructors are) but somehow forgot about that when I asked the question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe so.

However, if you were you implement another function, such as *tearDown()*, that would function essentially as an **@After** method, I would argue you might as well use them for readability, for the benefit of other collaborators or maybe even yourself.


The upside to using **@Before** and **@After** annotations is the that they avoid having to call a method at the beginning of each unit test, designed to save you the extra maintenance. If for some reason you had forgotten to add the call to your *setUp()* and/or *tearDown()* method, who knows what could go wrong.


This is, of course, if you need the EXACT SAME setup before each test. If you envision having a completely different setup for different unit tests, than perhaps you should look at the functionality of the class you are testing and ask yourself if perhaps you could modularize more.

Comment: I had already mentioned that someone forgetting to make the call to the `runSetupLogic()` is not the kind of difference I am looking for. The answer by Christian Wilkie (edited by Stefan Birkner) is exactly what I wanted. Silly of me to have forgotten that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The benifit comes from reporting.

In your method: runSetupLogic()

when ran from the start of a test, is reported within the test. Not as part of the setup and not as part of the initialization.

If the setup method fails, you get an accurate description of what failed... setup vs testing.

The before method allows you to isolate test failures from setup failures and allows the reporting solution to know as well.